# QWidget converted as object using PySide6-uic

Tags: qt, pyside6

I've made a widget using Qt Designer. When I convert it to python script using `pyside6-uic widget.ui -o ui_widget.py`, the resulting class is a child of `object` instead of `QWidget`. I checked the class in the designer and the ui and they are both OK:

- Qt Designer

[image]

- widget.ui

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>Form</class>
 <widget class="QWidget" name="Form">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>229</width>
    <height>228</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>Form</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>30</x>
     <y>20</y>
     <width>75</width>
     <height>23</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
   <property name="text">
    <string>widget</string>
   </property>
  </widget>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

- ui_widget.py

```py
from PySide6.QtCore import (QCoreApplication, QDate, QDateTime, QLocale,
    QMetaObject, QObject, QPoint, QRect,
    QSize, QTime, QUrl, Qt)
from PySide6.QtGui import (QBrush, QColor, QConicalGradient, QCursor,
    QFont, QFontDatabase, QGradient, QIcon,
    QImage, QKeySequence, QLinearGradient, QPainter,
    QPalette, QPixmap, QRadialGradient, QTransform)
from PySide6.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QPushButton, QSizePolicy, QWidget)

class Ui_Form(object):  # <- should be QWidget
    def setupUi(self, Form):
        if not Form.objectName():
            Form.setObjectName(u"Form")
        Form.resize(229, 228)
        self.pushButton = QPushButton(Form)
        self.pushButton.setObjectName(u"pushButton")
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QRect(30, 20, 75, 23))

        self.retranslateUi(Form)

        QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)
    # setupUi

    def retranslateUi(self, Form):
        Form.setWindowTitle(QCoreApplication.translate("Form", u"Form", None))
        self.pushButton.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("Form", u"widget", None))
    # retranslateUi
```

- Config:

```
python             3.9.13
PySide6            6.4.3
PySide6-Addons     6.4.3
PySide6-Essentials 6.4.3
setuptools         58.1.0
shiboken6          6.4.3
```

Do you have any clue of what can be the issue ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: There is absolutely no issue. That `Ui_Form` class is just a helper one that is used on an actual QWidget (or subclass) instance: you could create an instance of that form class for composition or for multiple inheritance. See the PyQt guide about [using Designer](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/designer.html), which is equally valid for PySide (except for the imports, obviously).

Comment: Thanks for the link and your support. I watched a tutorial where the author created the QWidget manually. I was expected to have the same behavior when using QtDesigner but not. It's working now. I'll juste edit the question in case someone is having the same issue.

Comment: Please don't add answers inside the question. If you really want, use the "Answer your question" button and use that field instead. Also, be aware that a QMainWindow created in Designer already has a central widget, and if `setCentralWidget()` is called again, the previous one will be immediately destroyed. There's usually little point in separating two UIs for the main window and its central widget: just create the complete main window in Designer.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of loading the component as :

```py
class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

        self.widget = Ui_Form2()   # <- Work only if Ui_Form2 is a QWidget, not object
        self.widget.setupUi(self)

        self.setCentralWidget(self.widget)
```

A QWidget must be created and populated.

```py
class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        
        # solution 1
        self.widget = QWidget(self)
        f = Ui_Form2()
        f.setupUi(self.widget)  # <- set the form within a QWidget
        self.setCentralWidget(self.widget)

        # solution 2 : preferred if the MainWindow is done with Qt Designer
        f = Ui_Form2()
        f.setupUi(self.ui.centralwidget)
```